# Can't build app with Ionic

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am no longer able to build my app and generate an apk anymore because an error shows up. Here is what happens when I try to build the app in the command prompt: [Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvM2W.png)

Can somebody please help me with this? Oh and this is what happens if I type ionic info in the command prompt:

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.4 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\Singh>ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v0.12.4



C:\Users\Singh>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the platform, and then add it again, and then build your application.

So, if you have android as targeted platform execute these commands:

```
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
```

Comment: @user3583688: yes, in the root directory of your application (root dir is where all your other folders like `www`, `plugins`, `platforms` are).

Comment: Nope, It didn't work. :( I removed and added the platform again and when I tried to build the app, it gave the same error code. I'm guessing that it has something to do with Gradle trying to build the app. It must be a bug or something. It's really annoying, I hope they fix it.

Answer (score 0):

My son had a very similar problem, and we never did figure out what caused it. He ended up creating a brand new blank ionic project, and then just copying the www folder from the old project. It worked, and he was able to get things building again. If you try it, you'll also have to re-add your plugins, copy package.json and bower.json, and then rerun `bower install` and `npm install`. It's not pleasant, but it might be worth a shot if you're desperate.